# Awkward phrasing of badge description with suggested update

Tags: discussion, badges, wording

It was suggested that I post this here, so I'm creating a copy here:

This is replacing [a previous question](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/21413) (deleted, so 10K only) on the [description of the Enlightened badge in the Help Center](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/badges/19/enlightened):

> First to answer and accepted with score of 10 or more. This badge can be awarded multiple times.

The phrasing of this explanation is incredibly awkward without punctuation.

A suggested alternate, clear wording from Daniel Fischer's comment in the previous question:

> First to answer, and the answer was accepted and has a score of at least ten. This badge can be awarded multiple times.

Comment: I migrated the original report from meta.math.se and marked this one as duplicate because the original one has more upvotes